# Summing a Cell across all sheets formatted as Duration

Tags: google-sheets, sum, duration

So i have a google sheets with multiple sheets for which i track my reading stats, each sheet is one book. I would like to have a totals sheet which displays some stats calculated for all my books(sheets).

For example i have cell with tracks the Duration a book has taken, its always the same cell in every sheet(I3) this cell uses the SUM() function to sum all the durations for each day.
Its formatted in the "Duration" mode in sheets it takes 01:20:59.000 and displays it as 1:20:59.

I would like a function which sums the duration for all for example I3 Cells in all my sheets.

I have tried various scripts i found to make this work, but non of them worked with the Duration Format just with plain numbers.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE({Sheet1!I3; Sheet2!I3}))); "[h]:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: First off, thanks for you effort. Unfortunately i get a Formula parse error when trying this.
Also one functionality i was looking for, was to sum up all sheets, so i don't have to add to the formula every time i make a new sheet i.e. read a new book.